# How to convert a docbook from version 4 to 5

Tags: docbook, docbook-5, docbook-xsl

Is there an automated way (or with minimal manual corrections) of converting docbook 4.3 books to the latest DocBook 5?

Comment: Some seconds of Google pointed me to http://doccookbook.sourceforge.net/html/en/dbc.structure.db4-to-db5.html - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The URL : https://docbook.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/docbook/trunk/docbook/relaxng/tools/db4-upgrade.xsl    don't work !!

Comment: What do you mean by that comment?

Comment: i can't download db4-upgrade.xsl because the URL don't work anymore

Comment: That was really simple: you should start using google. https://github.com/docbook/docbook/blob/master/relaxng/tools/db4-upgrade.xsl

Comment: Right, i already find the file but the command line xsltproc db4-upgrade.xsl doc.xml i don't know how to use it and how to install xsltproc on Windows

Comment: Then please try using Google. I found at least one tutorial about this

Comment: Here is the updated url for db4-upgrade.xsl  https://github.com/docbook/docbook/blob/docbook50-rewind/relaxng/tools/db4-upgrade.xsl